# Java avoiding null pointer exception in generic class

Tags: java, generics, nullpointerexception, binary-tree

Okay here are my two classes.My aim is to insert in OBT using generic class.In this case I am trying with Strings.When I call the insert method in the main I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at OBTComparable.insert(OBTComparable.java:37)
at FindTest.main(FindTest.java:12)
```

I found the problem: Since the var "data" is null , I can't use it to compare.

THE QUESTION:
How can i change the "data" to avoid the null pointer exception(It will be a String).

Generic OBTComparable class:

```
public class OBTComparable<Type extends Comparable<Type>>                         
{
  private boolean empty;

  private Type data;
  private OBTComparable left;
  private OBTComparable right;

  public OBTComparable()
  {
    setEmpty();
  }

  private void setEmpty()
  {
    empty = true;
    data = null;  /////////////////// THE PROBLEM //
    left = null;
    right = null;
  } 

  private void setData(Type reqData)
  {
    if (empty)
    {
      empty = false;
      left = new OBTComparable();
      right = new OBTComparable();
    }
    data = reqData;
  }


  public void insert(Type insertData)
  {
    int compare = data.compareTo(insertData); /////////////// HERE ALSO
    if (empty)
      setData(insertData);
    else if (compare < 0)
      left.insert(insertData);
    else
      right.insert(insertData);
  } 


  public boolean find(Type findData)
  {
    int compare = findData.compareTo(data);
    if (empty)
      return false;
    else if (compare == 0)
      return true;
    else if (compare < 0)
      return left.find(findData);
    else
      return right.find(findData);
  }    

  public int compareTo(OBTComparable<Type> other)
       { return 0; }

} // class
```

Test class:

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    OBTComparable<String> obt = new OBTComparable<String>();
    String [] insertStrings =
       new String [] { "My", "name", "is", "Mark", "Smith", "and", "my",
                      "hobbies", "include", "films", "music", "computing" };


    for (int i = 0; i < insertStrings.length; i++)
    {
      obt.insert(insertStrings[i]); //////////// HERE ALSO
      System.out.println("Inserting" + insertStrings[i]);
    }

 } // main
} // class
```

Comment: You should do the `data.compareTo(insertData)` in `insert()` after you check if it's empty. Also consider this in `find()`.

Answer (score 3):

In any method where you're referencing `data` before you call `setData` you're going to get this problem.

A rewrite of insert to get around this would be

```
public void insert(Type insertData)
{
    if (empty) 
    {
        setData(insertData);
    }
    else
    {
        int compare = data.compareTo(insertData);
        if (compare < 0)
            left.insert(insertData);
        else
            right.insert(insertData);
    }
}
```

You would need to apply similar changes to `find()`

You should also look at `Optional` as a way to represent values which may be null.  Ideally, the state of an object would be set in the constructor so you have a valid object immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Let's begin from your `main` method:

```
OBTComparable<String> obt = new OBTComparable<String>();
```

You initialize `obt` object, so the constructor is called, it has a method call`setEmpty()`, this method sets `data` to be `null`.

Then, the next statement in `main`:

```
obt.insert(insertStrings[i]);
```

And in the first line of it you're calling `compareTo` on the `data` object: `data.compareTo(insertData);`, but `data` is `null`, it's like writing:

```
int compare = null.compareTo(insertData);
```

which causes a `NullPointerException`.

Solution with a bonus tip:

`setData(insertData);` before using the `data` object.

Tip: Please use the debugger, it's there to help you. You'll really better understand the flow of your program when you use it.